# Inner Join with Count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the soul count of a player in the game as well as all their other stats. The query I am trying is

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 GROUP BY SoulLocationName WHERE SoulLocationName=t1.Name) AS SoulCount 
FROM tblAvatar t1
JOIN tblAvatar t2 ON t1.Name = t2.SoulLocationName
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.SoulCount 
FROM tblAvatar t1
JOIN(SELECT SoulLocationName,COUNT(*) as SoulCount FROM tblAvatar GROUP BY SoulLocationName) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.SoulLocationName
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. So what you are doing is joining to a table of select results named t2.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, 
COUNT(t2.SoulLocationName) as SoulCount 
FROM tblAvatar t1
JOIN tblAvatar t2 
ON t1.Name = t2.SoulLocationName
```